# Жёсткий диск и разные ФС

Tags: linux, файловая-система, kernel

Возник у меня такой интересный вопрос, ответ на который опытным путём получать не хочется :)

Допустим, есть жёсткий диск на котором есть тома, каждый из них форматирован и размечен разной ФС. Допустим, это XFS, BTRFS, EXT4 и NTFS.
Как мы знаем, каждая из ФС записывает информацию на диск по разному.
Суть вопроса:

Если одновременно начать записывать на каждый том файл с другого жёсткого диска (допустим 100гб и любым дистром Linux), как быстро такая нагрузка выведет жёсткий диск из строя? Как именно при этом будет распределять задачу копирования ядро Linux?

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что штатный режим использования диска (запись на него данных) должен вывести диск из строя?

Comment: *как быстро такая нагрузка выведет жёсткий диск из строя?* Сие не зависит от файловой системы. Но записывать лучше сначала в один том, потом в другой - это значительно снизит "метание" головок. *Как именно при этом будет распределять задачу копирования ядро Linux?* ЕМНИП в Линуксе реализован Новелловский лифт чтения-записи...

Comment: Если подбираете ФС максимально подходящую для SSD/flash, то так и пишите. А диск из строя может выйти из-за брака, а не только из-за особенностей реализации ФС.

Answer (score 3):

> как быстро такая нагрузка выведет жёсткий диск из строя?

Такая - это какая? Для диска типичный ввод-вывод. Его вообще не интересуют ни абстракции таблицы разделов ни файловые системы ни файлы и ничего о них не знает. У накопителя есть адресация LBA и команды записать блок по адресу LBA и прочитать блок по адресу LBA. При том, сама LBA адресация имеет право не иметь ничего общего с физическими свойствами накопителя - это широко используется в SSD, где один и тот же адрес LBA может легко указывать в разные места flash памяти на усмотрение контроллера диска.

> Как именно при этом будет распределять задачу копирования ядро Linux?

Вопрос по меньшей мере на отдельную книгу. В актуальном ядре есть как минимум 6 разных реализаций планировщика ввода-вывода:

- noop
- deadline
- CFQ
- blk-mq none
- Mq-deadline
- kyber

Первые 3 довольно давно уже существуют, вторые 3 из более новой инфраструктуры blk-mq (включена по-умолчанию начиная с 4.19 ядра)

Затем помножить на некоторое число настроек самих планировщиков, настройки page cache ядра, большое число разных файловых систем (каждая из которых может писать данные разным способом), и помножить на обилие опций этих самых файловых систем. Затем добавить, что аппаратный контроллер диска (или RAID-контроллер) имеет право самостоятельно перетасовать запросы к накопителям на своё усмотрение. Ну и в качестве вишенки на торте - учесть, как именно выполняется копирование, например, с O_DIRECT.

Поэтому правильный ответ: будет писать как получится учитывая кучу разных настроек.

Comment: У некоторых накопителей есть вращающиеся части, у всех есть температурный режим, так что не всё так однозначно.

Comment: @0andriy, вы о чём? Можете развернуть мысль, что именно не однозначно?

Comment: *Для диска типичный ввод-вывод.* Это трэш-тест, а не типичный ввод-вывод.

Comment: Это обычный ввод-вывод. То что накопители по своей сути и есть расходники не меняет того факта, что для них нет никакой разницы какая там таблица разделов и прочие ФС сделаны сверху. Можно сделать дикий random io имея всего одну файловую систему. Например, если разместить сверху большую СУБД. Или вообще не делать файловую систему, а работать с raw device. Если накопитель подыхает от выполнения обычных с точки зрения стандарта операций - значит накопитель хрень, берите что-то более приличное. Тем более HDD всегда и были расходниками.